# Why does Sheldon Axler Linear Algebra Done Right give such a long proof for this theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Like for 1.29, can't it just say 0 * any n-tuple will make the n-tupe contain only zeros because 0 times any number in the n-tuple is zero by scalar multiplication? same question for 1.30/1.31

[image]

[image]

Comment: For 1.29, we aren't necessarily working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and furthermore, you need to prove that $0*x = 0$ for any number $x$.

Comment: Not all vector spaces are spaces of tuples of numbers.

Comment: Because there is no spoon. We are talking about vectors in an abstract vector space, not members of some $\mathbb F^n$. There is no $n$-tuple that you can manipulate entrywise.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: It resorts only to defining axioms of vector spaces.

Comment: You are also implicitly assuming that $0\cdot\lambda=0$ for every $\lambda$ in the base field, which also demands to be proven (and the proof of that is most likely very similar to what Axler is doing for vector spaces). The proposition in Axler, on the other hand, doesn't need this assumption and in fact contains it as a corollary by viewing the base field as vector space over itself.